# wlan0 to eth0 Communication

Tags: networking, iptables

I have a Raspberry Pi 3b+ (AP) working as an **Access Point** router (hostapd). Its wlan0 is configured with the IP 192.168.4.1. 
And I have another Raspberry Pi 3b+ (Node-1) working as a **Client**. I have connected the **Client (Node-1)** with the **Access Point (AP)** by configuring wpa_supplicant.conf. Now the Client gets the IP 192.168.4.14 and communicates with the AP and vice versa. 
After that i connected an IP camera (192.168.1.64) with the Client using its eth0 (192.168.1.1). The Client Pi easily pings the IP Camera. 
Now I want my Access Point Pi to be able to ping the IP Camera (192.168.1.64).But when i try to do so the terminal of the AP Pi says that the host is unreachable.

I have tried to do to IP forwarding using the following link.

https://github.com/arpitjindal97/raspbian-recipes/blob/master/eth-to-wifi-route.sh

But still i am unable to ping the IP Camera from my Access Point. The whole scenario is shown below.

*Access Point Pi (wlan0: 192.168.4.1)* **<====>** *(wlan0: 192.168.4.14) Client* *Pi (eth0: 192.168.1.1)* **<====>** *(192.168.1.64) IP Camera*

All i want to do is to stream the IP Camera from the Access Point.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: you could enable ip-forwading on your 'Client Pi' which acts as a gateway. `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Comment: I have done it already.